# Is something + infinitive?

Tags: questions

> **Is** your goal **to win** the contest?
>
> **Is** the purpose of a pencil **to draw**?

Does this form of questions (**Is** something **to do**) sound natural to native English speakers?

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Are they natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are natural. But that doesn't mean that the construction always will be.

This is a property of the particular nouns *goal* and *purpose*. Each of them can take a 'to'-infinitive clause as their complement. Several other nouns work the same way: *intention*, *desire*.

But *fear* doesn't: "My fear is to jump out of a plane" is not idiomatic, because *fear* takes a "that" clause, or a noun phrase (which could be an "-ing" clause) with "of".

I'm not sure about *hope*: "My hope is to get there in time" sounds a bit odd to me, but I think that many people would be comfortable with it.

Comment: By the way, I'd like to draw your attention to the fact that my question is about questions - do questions having such a form sound natural? It seems that you've answered something different, no?

Comment: I'm certainly with you as regards ***hope*** (can't unilaterally decry it, but I don't really like it much). Might it be because ***hope*** is usually "verbified" in constructions that *also* include an infinitive marker? *(I hope **to get there** on time)*. Whereas we can't easily verbify nouns like ***goal*** and ***purpose***.

Comment: @Alexey: As Colin says, your examples are fine. But for many closely-related situations we'd often be more likely to ask using a *verb associated with the person we're asking*. Thus *Do you intend to do that?* rather than *Is it your intention to do that?* That second "circumlocutory" form is more stilted / formal.

Comment: True, @FumbleFingers. But in the cases Alexey asked about (with an impersonal subject), the questions are completely natural to my ear.

Comment: *I like being left alone* - fine. *I like to be left alone* - fine. *I fear being left alone* - fine. *I fear to be left alone* - WEIRD. On the other hand, *I hope to be left alone* is fine, but *I hope being left alone* is a complete non-starter. Not easy for the non-natives! :)